# Convert key/value pairs to object using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a set of key/value pairs that I would like to convert them as object. What is the best possible way to do this using lodash.

```
maps: {
  "Recipe1" : ["Sugar", "Milk", "Bread"],
  "Recipe2" : ["Rice", "Salt", "Carrots"] 
}
```

Looking for an out to look like below

```
{
  name: "Recipe1",
  ingredients: ["Sugar", "Milk", "Bread"]
},
{
  name: "Recipe2",
  ingredients: ["Rice", "Salt", "Carrots"]
}
```

Comment: For the output, did you mean `maps: [ { name: ..., ingredients: ... }, { name: ..., ingredients: ... } ]`?

Comment: `const result = Object.keys(maps).map(k => ({name: k, ingredients: maps[k]}));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Lodash:

```js
var maps = {
  "Recipe1" : ["Sugar", "Milk", "Bread"],
  "Recipe2" : ["Rice", "Salt", "Carrots"] 
};

var output = _.map(maps, function(value, key) { 
  return {name: key, ingredients: value};
});

console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `_.map(maps, (ingredients, name) => ({ name, ingredients }) )` is a lot less verbose.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts That's true.  I try to follow the syntax consistently used in the Lodash [docs](https://lodash.com/docs) for the benefit of those who are used to them when I answer questions having the `lodash` tag.  Also, personally, I'm not a huge fan of functions in which the _name_ of the arguments is critical to the output.

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty trivial to do without lodash, using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), a [destructured parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring), and [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) for the returned object:

```js
const maps = {
  "Recipe1" : ["Sugar", "Milk", "Bread"],
  "Recipe2" : ["Rice", "Salt", "Carrots"] 
}

const output = Object.entries(maps).map(
  ([name, ingredients]) => ({ name, ingredients })
)

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get an array of key/value pairs. Iterate the pairs array with [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get the `name` and `ingredients` params, and create the result object with[shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015):

```js
const maps = {
  "Recipe1" : ["Sugar", "Milk", "Bread"],
  "Recipe2" : ["Rice", "Salt", "Carrots"] 
};

const result = Object.entries(maps)
  .map(([name, ingredients]) => ({ name, ingredients }));
  
console.log(result);
```